# JSON: Trailing comma error still present after removing the trailing comma?

Tags: html, json, google-chrome-extension

Here is my JSON file:

```
{
  "name": "Testing",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "1, 2, 3",
  "permissions": ["storage"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["script.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

I am trying to create chrome extensions, and I've run into an error. When I try to upload the project it gives me an error on line 12 (the last comma) in the manifest.json, saying that there's no trailing commas allowed, yet **when I go to remove it, the error is still present.  Any idea why?**
Thanks!

Comment: The error list on `chrome://extensions` page isn't cleared automatically, there's a button in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to remove the comma on line 11 behinde `"index.html"`.

That's the only possible problem I see on this.